Running two Task async context throws System.ObjectDisposedException
Can someone explain what I'm missing?
I'm trying to create a safe testing while in development mode. My test emails are from the database table called SystemSettings, it was working when I used it on a Controller but when I tried to use it inside the helper class called Messenger.cs and triggers SafeTestingSendEmail()  it throws System.ObjectDisposedException.
The error says I'm trying to use two of the same context instance which is _repoSystemSettings.SystemSettings.GetSystemSettings(type). I'm trying to get the value of the column Value from the database table column Name which are DEV_BCC_EMAIL and DEV_EMAIL
this should be what my database table looks like:



Id
Name
Value




1
DEV_BCC_EMAIL
"myBcc@gmail.com,myPersonal@gmail.com"


2
DEV_EMAIL
"myPersonal@gmail.com"



SystemSettingsRepo.cs
public class SystemSettingsRepo : ISystemSettingsRepo
{
    readonly DbContext _context;
    public SystemSettingsRepo(DbContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetSystemSettings(string type = "")
    {
        var settings = await _context.SystemSettings.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.IsActive == true && s.Name == type);
        return settings.Value;
    }

}

ISystemSettingsRepo.cs [Interface]
public interface ISystemSettingsRepo
{
    Task<string> GetSystemSettings(string type = "");
}

This is the helper class I'm working on:
I'm trying to determine the env mode and if it falls to "development" then it should use the "DEV_BCC_EMAIL" or "DEV_EMAIL" types and retrieve the value from the database. This is where I tried to call two of the same context but different filter. I've used Task.delay() as to make time before calling the next context.
Messenger.cs
private readonly ISystemSettingsRepo _repoSystemSettings;

public Messenger(ISystemSettingsRepo repoSystemSettings) {
  _repoSystemSettings = repoSystemSettings;
}

public async void SafeTestingSendEmail(string receiver, string subject, string body, string cc = "")
 {
   
     var env;
     var bcc = "defaultBcc@email.com";
     if (env.Length > 0 && env != "production")
     {

         var devBcc = await GetSystemSettingValue("DEV_BCC_EMAIL");
         var devEmail = await GetSystemSettingValue("DEV_EMAIL");

         receiver = devEmail;
         bcc = devBcc;
         cc = bcc;
         subject += "Testing Email.";

         SendEmail(receiver, subject, body, bcc, cc);
     }
     else
     {
         // production logic
     }


 }

 public async Task<string> GetSystemSettingValue(string type)
 {
     await Task.Delay(2000);
     return await _repoSystemSettings.GetSystemSettings(type);
 }

I was expecting to retrieve the value from the GetSystemSettings(type) and successfully send email in development or production mode. I tried using Task.delay() and Task.Run() but it doesn't seem to work.

Edit:
I've solved the issue, but we're not using Task anymore.
Here's how I've solve it. Instead of using Task, I used List in retrieving records for the database table. This mean I didn't use async approach. I changed all types rules to List<SystemSettings>. If there was a better approach, let me know! Let's share ideas.

Is this really .net and C# 2.0 ?? Cannot really believe that.

public async void SafeTestingSendEmail should be public async Task SafeTestingSendEmail to begin with.

How do you register ISystemSettingsRepo / SystemSettingsRepo with DI? And please fix the versions in your tags. I guess that was an accident.

Sorry everyone, fixed the versions!

Still the .net-2.0 tag refers to ".NET Framework 2.0" - so still seems incorrect. Is it?

Yes, we are using .NET Framework v2.2 to be exact. It's a legacy code that we're trying to fix and revive. @Fildor

Please edit the question so that it presents a minimal reproducible example.

"It's a legacy code that we're trying to fix and revive." - I am going to tell you something you won't like, but it has to be said: Don't. It's dead. It's already decaying and smelling really bad. Go through the code, note down what it is supposed to do, then implement that in contemporary tooling.

I've said the same things @Fildor, corporate is a scary thing.

You have no using blocks, nor calls to Dispose: therefore this is not a sufficient example to show the problem. (And the difference between Framework and Core is very significant: this cannot be .NET Framework 2.0 because there were no Task, async, nor await back in 2005.

@Richard Idk man, it says .Net 2.2 with c#-7.3 and it's a .net core mvc. The system web app uses a lot of Task, async, and await all over it's appropriate files. Tbh it's working in the controllers, idk why it's not working in the helper class. Still editing the question to be more clear.

@thestoneoflapiz that's .NET Core 2.2. There never was a .NET Framework 2.2. And even .NET Core 2.2 reached end of life 5 years ago. The earliest supported .NET (Core) version is .NET 6

@thestoneoflapiz that said, the only way to get an ObjectDisposedException is to actually try and use a disposed object. It's not a .NET issue. async void is only meant for asynchronous event handlers, because such methods can't be awaited. If you call such a method, the caller will keep running and possibly dispose any objects still needed by that method

@thestoneoflapiz thanks for the clear there lots of bugs and issues in the posted code. That async void is a critical bug - that code never worked. Using something with 5 years of unpatched security issues is a big problem. EF Core 2.2 had a lot of quirks that stopped working in EF Core 3.1 (we're at 8 now). Even SystemSettingsRepo is extremely unusual. .NET Core uses the Configuration middleware for settings and using the database as a source is the example in the Custom Configuration source docs

"I've said the same things, corporate is a scary thing." - don't tell, just do it. Because in order to "revive" the functionality that's what needs to be done. There is no "fixing" it. It's beyond repair.

If they don't listen or threaten you, make them sign a waver that puts all responsibility for resulting legal and financial liabilities on their shoulders. Sometimes, you need to be graphic. ( Yes, I've done that before and guess who got a "Oh, if it is that serious ..." )

And yes, it is that serious - as in willful negligence and liability kind of serious. If the company insists on using software that hasn't been patched in over 5 years, guess who's liable it there's a security breach due to bugs fixed in the past 5 years? And who's responsible for ensuring that software is safe?

a safe testing while in development mode that mode is automatically handled by the Configuration middleware, which loads different settings JSON files depending on the environment specified by the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT and DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT environment variables. That's not a new feature, .NET Core always had the ability to load different settings for Development, Staging, Production.
